# camunda variables aren't shown in tasklist form

Tags: camunda

I'm able to see the filled up variables in cockpit like that:
[image]
but in tasklist they aren't shown, there's only the forms which should be filled out in the next step (doesn't mater which user is logged in...):
[image]
it should look like that, where the filled variables are shown (camunda-invoice example):
[image]

I'm new at camunda... I'm using the latest version (camunda BPM platform v7.2.0). How can I fix that? Should it be done in the .bpmn or in the webinterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add readonly form fields in the .bpmn